# Change isPresent() and method invocation into ifPresent()

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

How can I change:

```
if (pAlarms[0].getMoIdentifier().isPresent()) {
    Optional<AlarmValue[]> alarmValues = getAlarmsFromMo(pAlarms[0].getMoIdentifier().get());
}
```

into `ifPresent()`?

Comment: Your edit has now made this post opinion based. 1) please avoid changing the initial focus of the question. 2) questions such as _Which is better?_ can get lots of different opinions instead of _facts_ so please avoid. thanks :).

Comment: I rolled back your edit. You should not change your question like that when you already got answers because it invalidates them. Your edit also made your question opinion based as Aominè said.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you asked for using `ifPresent()`, I think using `flatMap()` makes a lot more sense in your example. With it you should be able to do this:

```
Optional<AlarmValue[]> alarmValues = pAlarms[0].getMoIdentifier().flatMap(this::getAlarmsFromMo)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
pAlarms[0].getMoIdentifier().ifPresent(moId -> {
    Optional<AlarmValue[]> alarmValues = getAlarmsFromMo(moId);
});
```

Comment: Note that the `Optional<AlarmValue[]>` will be used in any way (i guess or what the point ;) ), meaning a lot of line in that lambda expression, so I would sugesst to extract the logic into a method accepting a parameter to call it with a methd reference. (Just a side note)

Comment: Well yes, likely the lambda will do more than just throw away method results, and should be extracted to a proper method. But just working with the code given..

Comment: The note was not for you @Kayaman ;) OP's might start to write a big lambda giving a terrible code, so I preferred to add this comment here.

Comment: I did exactly like @Kayaman wrote and my lambda function has 3 more lines. I think this isn't a mistake.